# Is there a cleaner way of creating an array?

Tags: php, class

My php example returns an array that works, but I would like to keep everything inside "class CreateAccount".

This is the way I do it today, and it doesn't look so good but it works. Is there a better way of doing it?

```
<?php
class CreateAccount {

     public function __construct($id,$namne,$fromdate,$group,$comment,$firstnamne,$org,$sid,$todate)
    {
        $this->countrows = null;
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->namne = $namne;
        $this->fromdate = $fromdate;
        $this->group = $group;
        $this->comment = $comment;
        $this->firstname = $firstnamne;
        $this->org = $org;
        $this->sid = $sid;
        $this->todate = $todate;
    }
}

/* Fill your Contact Object */
$contact = new CreateAccount("x6529","Jon Doe","2019-01-16","STD_GROUP","Guest User","Helen Doe","HQ","200410201234","2019-01-17");

/* Set your parameters for the request */
$params = array(
  "application" => 'api',
  "account" => $contact,
);

print_r($params);
?>


Array
(
    [application] => api
    [account] => CreateAccount Object
        (
            [countrows] => 
            [id] => x6529
            [namne] => Jon Doe
            [fromdate] => 2019-01-16
            [group] => STD_GROUP
            [comment] => Guest User
            [firstname] => Helen Doe
            [org] => HQ
            [sid] => 200410201234
            [todate] => 2019-01-17
        )

)
```

Comment: _I would like to keep everything inside "class CreateAccount"._ What is stopping you?

Comment: By default all members are publically available which means anyone can modify anything, I would suggest adding a 'private' modifier, then add get / set methods to ensure correct access and parsing of the data.

Comment: Code Review is a good place to post working code and get comprehensive feedback.  Read how to post before posting.

Comment: @mickmackusa - This is more of a question how to include all parts into the class and get a multidimensional array back.

Comment: My advice remains unchanged.

Comment: On this site, you are likely to receive "this will work answers". At CodeReview you will receive "this is what you **should** do and **why**" answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up doling like this:

```
class CreateAccount {

    public function __construct($application,$id,$name,$fromdate,$group,$comment,$firstname,$org,$sid,$todate)
    {
        $this->application = $application;
        $this->gastkonto['countrows'] = null;
        $this->gastkonto['id'] = $id;
        $this->gastkonto['name'] = $name;
        $this->gastkonto['fromdate'] = $fromdate;
        $this->gastkonto['group'] = $group;
        $this->gastkonto['comment'] = $comment;
        $this->gastkonto['firstname'] = $firstname;
        $this->gastkonto['org'] = $org;
        $this->gastkonto['sid'] = $sid;
        $this->gastkonto['todate'] = $todate;
    }
}

/* Fill your Contact Object */
$contact = new CreateAccount("api","x6529","Jon Doe","2019-01-16","STD_GROUP","Guest User","Helen Doe","HQ","200410201234","2019-01-17");

print_r($contact);
```

Comment: Your first `$contact` is unneeded and possibly will cause bugs. Class declarations don't usually hold many values, let alone a whole instantiation. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54219272/3626537).

Comment: Thanks @Phrancis, Misstake from me, I've now removed the contact inside the class in code above.

Comment: OK. Consider accepting the answer that best helped you solve your problem, too.

Answer (score 0):

PHP have a function `get_object_vars` to get all the properties of a object. And because you're making dynamic properties in constructor. So, we defined a method `getAccount` which will get all the properties in an array `$properties` then we iterate through this and put all info in one array `$account` and finally we return this array.

```
<?php
class CreateAccount {

    public function __construct($id,$namne,$fromdate,$group,$comment,$firstnamne,$org,$sid,$todate)
    {
        $this->countrows = null;
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->namne = $namne;
        $this->fromdate = $fromdate;
        $this->group = $group;
        $this->comment = $comment;
        $this->firstname = $firstnamne;
        $this->org = $org;
        $this->sid = $sid;
        $this->todate = $todate;
    }

    public function getAccount()
    {
        $properties = get_object_vars($this);
        $account    = [];
        foreach($properties as $property)
        {
            $account[$property] = $this->{$property};
        }
        return $account;
    }
}

/* Fill your Contact Object */
$contact = new CreateAccount("x6529","Jon Doe","2019-01-16","STD_GROUP","Guest User","Helen Doe","HQ","200410201234","2019-01-17");

/* Set your parameters for the request */
$params = array(
  "application" => 'api',
  "account" => $contact->getAccount(),
);

print_r($params);
?>
```